# Считывание из файла символов в массив

Tags: java

Как считать символы из файла в массив?

```
File file = new File("D:/Test.txt");
```

Открываю файл, создаю массив, а дальше что?

Comment: Считывай символы из открытого файла в созданный массив =)

Comment: @Free_ze, как?)

Comment: @dayz2dayz
Гугл ит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    if (!file.exists()) {
      System.out.println(args[0] + " does not exist.");
      return;
    }
    if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
      System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
      return;
    }
    try {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      char current;
      while (fis.available() > 0) {
        current = (char) fis.read();
        System.out.print(current);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @huxi, @Free_ze, а можно ли считать данные в массив не посимвольно, а целым куском текста? Мне просто нужно в данном куске текста искать слова и комбинации слов.

Comment: @dayz2dayz, а Вы [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) вообще читаете?

Comment: @dayz2dayz, выделите массив байт размером с файл и [считайте](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) целиком.